# Proving a matrix is triangular

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

linear algebra proof I'm having trouble with:

Let A be a square matrix. Prove that there exists a matrix $B$ so that $BA$ is a triangular matrix.

I tried turning it into a homogeneous system of equations but it got really messy really fast, so I'm thinking I need to think of a way to take the different possibilities for $A$ into account. For example, if A has an inverse then the question is obviously redundant - its inverse will turn it into $I$ which is itself a triangular matrix. If $A=0$ the same is true since the $0$ matrix is also triangular. The problem is proving that $BA$ is triangular while $A$ doesn't have an inverse and $A\neq 0$.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, you can take $B = 0$. If you want $B$ to be invertible, then recall that left multiplication by an invertible $B$ is equivalent to performing a sequence of row operations on $A$. Using a sequence of row operations, the matrix $A$ can be brought to [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form), which, for a square matrix, means in particular that it will be upper triangular.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, given any invertible matrix B, when multiplied by some A who may or may not be invertible, the result is the same as performing certain row operations on that A? How can I "guarantee" that A has a triangular form via these operations?

Comment: Are you familiar with Gaussian elimination? It is an algorithm used for solving a system of linear equations which transforms a given matrix by using row operations (which don't change the space of solutions) to a special form called row echelon form (or reduced row echelon form) which in particular is upper triangular.

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with Gaussian elimination but I guess what I'm asking is can ANY matrix be reduced to rref by multiplying it on the right with some invertible matrix? I know how to use elementary row operations to find the inverse of a matrix but that can't be done on a non-invertible matrix, can it?

Comment: Yes. Every elementary row operation can be implemented by multiplying the matrix $A$ by the corresponding elementary matrix (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) which is invertible. If you perform a sequence of $k$ row operations on $A$, it corresponds to multiplying $A$ on the left by $R_k \ldots R_1 A = (R_k \ldots R_1) A$ and since each $R_i$ is invertible, their product $R_k \ldots R_1$ is also invertible.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about the Echelon form and elementary matrices: by applying row operations, you can turn $A$ into its Echelon form, which is upper triangular. This is achieved by applying the product $B$ of all the elementary matrices corresponding to the row operations you did: so $BA$ is upper triangular.